# How to make keep-alive header response?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, http-headers, keep-alive, asp.net-core-webapi

I try to make simple Web API application with GET and POST.When I response to a GET request:

```
 {
    "status": "OK",
    "headers":
    {
        "Date": "Fri, 18 Aug 2017 16:50:38 GMT",
        "Transfer-Encoding": "chunked",
        "Connection": "close",
        "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        "Server": "Kestrel"
    },
    "body": "....",
    "code": 200,
    "protocol": "HTTP/1.1"
}
```

But I want to make `"Connection": "keep-alive"`, not `"Connection": "close"` so I changed my config.

Startup.cs:

```
 public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app,
                       IHostingEnvironment env,
                       ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
    loggerFactory.AddDebug();
    app.UseMvc();
    app.UseSession();
    app.Run(async (context) =>
    {
        context.Response.Headers[HeaderNames.Connection] = "Keep-Alive";
    });                    
}
```

But, I get a `"Connection": "close"` response.

Any idea how to change to the `"keep-alive"` setting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTTP/1.1 defines the "close" connection option for the sender to signal that the connection will be closed after completion of the response. For example, *Connection: close* in either the request or the response header fields indicates that the connection SHOULD NOT be considered `persistent' after the current request/response is complete.

If you are trying to achieve a persistent connection, you may want to look into websockets.